# How do I get Netbeans to default to Hex display for watch variables?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, hex

In Netbeans 6.5 I am debugging a network stream and need to view the memory in Hex. The only way I have found to do this is to right click on each row and select display as Hex. This is very inefficient and I would like either a memory dump or default to hex. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Looks like the context option you're using now is it.  See the bottom of this [netbeans.org page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/QuestionsOnDebuggerSettings).
- Questions on the Netbeans forums relating to a global hex display option in the debugger remain unanswered ([for example](http://forums.netbeans.org/search.php?search_author=kyohe2)).
- You might try out a [hex editor plugin](https://hexeditor.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Java Debugger -> Variable Formatters.
2. Click the “Add...” button.
3. In the “Add Variable Formatter” dialog enter:

---

- Formatter name: “MyHexByte”. Class types: “java.lang.Byte”.
- Value formatted as a result of code snipped:

  **"0x" +
     java.lang.Integer.toHexString(byteValue() & 0xFF)**
- Click “OK”.

---

4. Click the “Apply “button in the Java Debugger dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly about individual bytes, but I keep a special watch in my watch expression list for when I need to see what a byte array holds:

```
new java.math.BigInteger(1, myByteArray).toString(16)
```

When I need it, I simply change the byte array name to whatever local variable I want to check. This hex representation matches what I see in my hex editor, which is what I need.